# Can get JSON from Google Maps call

Tags: php, json, google-maps

I have managed to get the longitude and latitude of postcodes from Google Maps but I am unable to then get the distance between the two. The following url gives me some JSON:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.6896118,-0.7846495&destinations=51.7651382,-3.7914676&units=imperial&sensor=false
```

But I can't strip it out using PHP:

```
<?php
    $du = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.6896118,-0.7846495&destinations=51.7651382,-3.7914676&units=imperial&sensor=false";
    $djd = json_decode(utf8_encode($du),true);
    print("-".$djd."-");
?>
```

Anybody know why this is?

**EDIT**

The following worked just fine:

```
<?php
    $pc1 = 'SA92NH';
    $pc2 = 'HP270SW';
    $url1 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$pc1."&sensor=false";
    $url2 = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$pc2."&sensor=false";
    $url1_data = file_get_contents($url1);
    $url2_data = file_get_contents($url2);
    $json1_data = json_decode(utf8_encode($url1_data),true);
    $json2_data = json_decode(utf8_encode($url2_data),true);
    $longlat1 = $json1_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json1_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    $longlat2 = $json2_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'].",".$json2_data['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    print($longlat1."<br>\n");
    print($longlat2."<br>\n");
?>
```

Comment: If you intend for this to work, you are missing code to generate a request.

Comment: I'm trying to JSON decode the returned data from google maps

Comment: datasage: how do you mean?

Comment: Use CURL or file_get_contents (whith external docs enabled) to get the url content

Comment: @Sevenearths, `json_decode()` takes a JSON string as argument, but you're not passing it a JSON string, you're passing it the string representing the URL. You need to download the data found at that URL, which is a JSON string, and use that with `json_decode()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?
You need to get the data, you cannot only type the url.

In my example i use get [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

```
<?php
    $du = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.6896118,-0.7846495&destinations=51.7651382,-3.7914676&units=imperial&sensor=false");
    $djd = json_decode(utf8_encode($du),true);
    print_r($djd);
?>
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/LqxpJW

Comment: Thats exactly what I am talking about. My server won't print the decoded JSON though?!?

Comment: but in your example you don't use file_get_contents.

Comment: just tried it with `file_get_contents` and it works fine!?!? very strange because I used the approach above to retrieve the long,lats of the post codes (prior to this function) and it worked fine

Comment: @Sevenearths, can you post that code where it worked without using `file_get_contents()`?

Comment: @Sevenearths, I see that you *are* using `file_get_contents()`: `$url1_data = file_get_contents($url1)`.

Comment: @rid: your right, your right, your right! sometimes I don't even know my own code :o

Comment: I am marking this one as the correct answer because he was the first one to the punch

Comment: @rid I now saw it was a copy and paste error in my answer. I was about to answer the same as this, but had the question itself in clipboard :!!! Now understand problems with my answer. ;) +1 for this

Comment: @rid It is answered now, and that's ok (and the sense of SO). Was a bad day-start for me, but see me on other questions.... ;) however, sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=51.6896118,-0.7846495&destinations=51.7651382,-3.7914676&units=imperial&sensor=false';

$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);
```

And after that access $json like an array !
 Something like that:

```
echo $json['rows']['elements']['distance']['text'];
```